# Admin access to Domain User's Gmail?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm currently writing an auditing script that is focusing on users' gmails and need access to their message lists. I have admin access and scopes for the AdminSDK, the script will be executed by the admin.

I'm wondering how exactly to do this? I have my domain's userlist via Directory, but I can't use GmailApp with a specific user, only the current user(admin). I was also thinking about assigning a timed Trigger to each of the users and using GmailApp locally, but I can't figure out how to do that either(I don't think this is possible).

One idea that I'm working on is pinging the Gmail API using the admin's credentials via URLFetchApp, but can I get my domain's users information with this method?

What are your thoughts? Any guidance will be appreciated.
I'm currently using GAS on a service account.

Comment: Sounds like a snooper's charter

Answer (score 0):

While using service account, you can impersonate users in your domain and perform actions on their behalf. For this you will need to perform domain wide delegation of authority in your domain.

Here you can find documentation about [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation).

Here you can see an [example](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation), I know is on Drive but the principle is the same.

Hope this helps.